# Pygame error with pickling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pickle

I have a pygame game, before I tried to pickle It worked perfectly, but afterwards 
I started to get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Knowhaw\Desktop\Python Programs\Brick Breaker\BrickBreaker.pyw", line                            
253, in <module>
    play(paddle, ball, pickle.load(open("Levels/leveltest.lvl", "rb")))
  File "C:\Users\Knowhaw\Desktop\Python Programs\Brick Breaker\BrickBreaker.pyw", line   
227, in play
    screen.blit(brick.sprite, (brick.x, brick.y))
pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

I am led to believe this has something to do with deep copying, is there an alternative to 
pickle which does not use deep copying, or any other solution?

Here is a portion of the code: http://pastebin.com/gqi91Ckq

If you require any further information, just ask.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to pickle (and why)? Does the problem occur during pickling or during unpickling?

Comment: the problem occurs during unpickling, or during blitting the unpickled images, I'm unpickling a list of brick objects (I can give you the code for the brick class if you wish), which I'm trying to unpickle so you can save created levels.

Comment: Yes, show the code. Also show the code where you pickle them.

Comment: You probably ended up pickling the handle to the display or something.

Comment: here is all the relevant code: http://pastebin.com/gqi91Ckq

Comment: I solved it, I can't pickle the images, so I redetermine them from how broken it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I can't pickle the images, so I redetermine them from how broken the brick is is